# Unable to use Form inside tabs in ReactBootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

```
render(){
return(<div>
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
<Form>  
<Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
  </Tabs>
  <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
    <input type="text" name="age"/>
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact" disabled>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </Tab>
</Form>
</Tabs></div>);
}
```

**Unable to use Form inside tabs in ReactBootstrap. The `Tab` component is not meant to be rendered! It's an abstract component that is only valid as a direct Child of the `Tabs` Component. For custom tabs components use TabPane and TabsContainer directly. This is very important form me. I need the whole form devided in different forms Thank You**

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the whole <Tabs> with <Form>?

Comment: yes. I Tried Like that only. I need separate inputs of the form in separate tabs

Comment: I have asked whether you have put form above tabs. In your example form is inside tabs. So move the <Form> one line higher and </Form> between </Tabs> and </div> and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should have Tab inside Tabs component.

[image: Example of how to use tab and tabs]

Please find the screenshot of sample output on how to use tabs and tab.

Comment: dear sir, still I'm getting the same error. I just want only one form to be rendered within all tabs

Comment: I am trying to understand the use case here. You want one form to be displayed in all the tab?

Comment: Hope this helps. https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-microservice-ru9v1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Dear Sir, Not Like this But a single form should render in all tabs. As in my piece of code, one inputbox in in first tab, and another inputbox is in second tab and submit button is in 3rd tab and after that form tag is closed. I want like that

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your closing tag. Maybe this causing the error:

```
<Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
</Tabs>
```